# Who has included whom to get definition?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I have simple dialog based `MFC` application. It contains variable `HWND blabla`. `HWND` is defined in `windef.h`. I don't see any includes of `windef.h` in my code. Possible other headers does that.

Now I need to create hello world `MFC` dialog application with `HWND blabla` variable. And I would like to have the `HWND` definition in the same way that it was in the first application.

How to know who has included whom to get the `HWND` definition in the first application?

Are there are any tools to retrieve this information?

Comment: `#include "windows.h"`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdkef6tk.aspx

Comment: Simplest way: use the wizards to start your new project, making sure to select that you will be using MFC.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the mfc the windows headers are all included with the afxwin.h or afx.h headers.

- Also never include windows.h by yourselfin a MFC project.
- Also never include windef.h, always include windows.h, no other header.

Comment: which is one of the biggest WTFs about MFC because you might want to include headers that are non-MFC but use Win32 and need to include windows.h

Comment: Why? Where is the problem? Feel free and include only windows.h in a cpp file that doesn't use the MFC. Even with precompiled header files you find a way. Just disable this for the specific files or use your own.

Comment: ... Also you can always include windows.h, do it as you like. But afx.h must always be included first if needed!

Comment: precompiled headaches are an even bigger WTF. Why should it be a fatal error if a compilation unit doesn't use it. It's only supposed to be something to make the compile time quicker.

Comment: Those who work for a company where they are used. Or usually misused. As well as the likely heavy overuse of COM when regular DLLs will suffice.

Comment: Because this option can be easily disabled for a group of source files it is really never a problem, even if forced to use it. But this doesn't belong to the question here...

Comment: @CashCow It works that way because of how it's implemented. Yes, it's weird.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very easy way to see all your includes. Just select in project properties
**Configuration properties -> C/C++ -> Show includes = /showIncludes** and build your project. In build output you will see all information you need. In your case windef.h path:

```
stadfx.h -> afxwin.h -> afx.h -> afxver_.h -> afxv_w32.h -> windows.h -> windef.h
```